# Не создается макет в onCreate при добавлении нового параллельного потока

Tags: java, android, асинхронность

При данном коде сначала выполняется создание нового потока, действия с ним, а уже после создается сам макет MainActivity (setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)). При работе нового потока, экран просто белый, без макета. Действие заканчивается нового потока, макет создается. Но ведь они здесь параллельные, вроде не должен новый поток как-то мешать.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

//static EggVoice mAnotherOpinion; //Побочный поток

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");

    anotherMethod();
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG,"onStart");
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,"onResume");
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG,"onPause");
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG,"onStop");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy");
}

public void anotherMethod(){
    anotherThread();
}

public void anotherThread(){
    EggVoice mAnotherOpinion;
    mAnotherOpinion = new EggVoice();   //Создание потока
    Log.d(TAG,"Спор начат...");
    mAnotherOpinion.start();            //Запуск потока

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"курица!");
    }

    //Слово «курица» сказано 5 раз

    if(mAnotherOpinion.isAlive())   //Если оппонент еще не сказал последнее слово
    {
        try{
            mAnotherOpinion.join(); //Подождать пока оппонент закончит высказываться.
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}

        Log.d(TAG,"Первым появилось яйцо!");
    }
    else    //если оппонент уже закончил высказываться
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"Первой появилась курица!");
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"Спор закончен!");
}
}
```

EggVoice:

```
public class EggVoice extends Thread {
private static final String TAG = "EggVoice";

@Override
public void run()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"яйцо!");
    }
    //Слово «яйцо» сказано 5 раз
}
}
```

в Log'ах такая информация:

```
MainActivity: onCreate
MainActivity: Спор начат...
    курица!
MainActivity: курица!
    курица!
    курица!
    курица!
EggVoice: яйцо!
    яйцо!
    яйцо!
EggVoice: яйцо!
    яйцо!
MainActivity: Первым появилось яйцо!
    Спор закончен!
MainActivity: onStart
MainActivity: onResume
```

Поясните, пожалуйста, все эти действия и постсоздание макета.

Comment: Активность не создана до тех пор, пока не завершено выполнение метода `onCreate`. Метод `onCreate` не завершится, пока не завершится `anotherMethod`. А `anotherMethod` будет ждать завершения потока в точке вызовы `mAnotherOpinion.join()`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, вы правы, можно ли узнать у Вас, действительно ли здесь параллельные потоки, которые выполняются одновременно?

Comment: Здесь два потока, которые могут выполняться параллельно, если не вызывать `join`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо за ваши ответы, вы действительно очень качественно всё разъяснили. Основной вопрос решен, хотелось бы отметить его как правильный, можете его опубликовать в ответах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Активность не создана до тех пор, пока не завершено выполнение метода `onCreate`. Метод `onCreate` не завершится, пока не завершится `anotherMethod`. А `anotherMethod` будет ждать завершения потока в точке вызова `mAnotherOpinion.join()`.

Comment: благодарна вам за разъяснения

Comment: На самом деле говорить что активность не создана до окончания выполнения onCreate() неправильно. Метод onCreate() вызывается как раз у созданного экземпляра Activity. Просто Activity становится видимой для пользователя только после вызова onStart()